# Loading .bmp into Texture2D

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, xna, textures

I need to load a .bmp file into a Texture2D. To do this, I am using

```
 blank =   Content.Load<Texture2D("C:\\Users\\Moray\\Desktop\\TP6\\GameMap\\GameMap\\GameMapContent\\blank");
```

First, while the command executes, there is an error saying that the file cannot be opened.

Second, I am using the full path of the image and that won't work on other computers. The reason I do so, is that when I use `Content.RootDirectory + "\\map.bmp"`, it says that the file could not be found.

What can I do to solve these issues?

Comment: You could try `Texture2D.FromFile()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put the extension, just Content.LoadTexture2D("nameOfYourFile_Without_The_Extension");

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the image on the project using Visual Studio? At the right you have

'NameOfYourProject[Content]'. Click on it, then 'add an existing element', browse your file and put it.

Second, when you use `Content.Load<Texture2D>("path/to/my/file")` you are browsing your ProjectContent, you don't put the full path, and you don't put the file extension, XNA will not understand if you do.

Comment: For blank.bmp I have Copy to output Directory : Copy Always and even I use the extension or not, it says that the file couldn't be found.

Comment: XNA uses a `.contentproj` file to list all the content you imported in your project. It does not matter if you put the file in the right directory. You have to import it the right way so that XNA add it to its 'list of content files'.